# how to addError function in yii2 model

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

i want make form for change password, with field old password and new password like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'old_password')->textInput()->label('Old Password  ') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->label(' New Password ') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'confirm_password')->passwordInput()->label('Confirm new password') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Change', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-fill']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I have controller like this

```
public function actionPass()
{
    $id=Yii::$app->user->id;
    $modelUser = $this->findModel($id);
    try { 
        $model = new \frontend\models\ChangePasswordForm($id);
    } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
    }

    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ( $model->validate() && $model->changePassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Password success to change ');
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'modelUser' => $modelUser,
            ]);

        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Password failed to change!');
            return $this->render('index', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelUser' => $modelUser,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

i have model to manage change password process

```
class ChangePasswordForm extends Model
{
public $id;
public $password;
public $confirm_password;
public $old_password;

/**
 * @var \common\models\User
 */
private $_user;

/**
 * Creates a form model given a token.
 *
 * @param  string                          $token
 * @param  array                           $config name-value pairs that will be used to initialize the object properties
 * @throws \yii\base\InvalidParamException if token is empty or not valid
 */
public function __construct($id, $config = [])
{
    $this->_user = User::findIdentity($id);

    if (!$this->_user) {
        throw new InvalidParamException('Unable to find user!');
    }

    $this->id = $this->_user->id;
    parent::__construct($config);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['password','confirm_password'], 'required'],
        [['password','confirm_password'], 'string', 'min' => 8],
        ['confirm_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
        ['old_password','findPasswords'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Changes password.
 *
 * @return boolean if password was changed.
 */
public function changePassword()
{
    $user = $this->_user;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    //$user->ps=$this->password;

    return $user->save();
}

public function findPasswords($attribute, $params, $validator)
{
    $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
    if (!Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->old_password, $user->password_hash))
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The Old Password not match.');
}
   }
```

the error validation for new password and confirm new password works, but not for old password field, the error not show in form when i fill password that not match with old password. Any help?

Comment: Does the model pass validation if you fill the new password and confirm password correctly and the old password incorrectly?

Comment: please add `old_password` to required fields and `var_dump($model->errors)` in your form and tell me about the result

Comment: @MichalHynčica, the model not pass validation, but the error not show

Comment: @mahsaa,  the result from var_dump is array(0) { }

Comment: when i add old_password to required, the error show when i left the old_password empty

Comment: You should add `old_password` to required fields because in `validatePassword` if `$password === ''` it will throw InvalidArgumentException

Comment: please add die('somthing') to if in findPasswords() and make sure your condition is satisfied.

Comment: @mahsaa, i am sory i don't understand,  Is this what you mean `if (!Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->old_password, $user->password_hash))
            $this->addError($attribute, 'The Old Password not match.');
        else die('somthing');`

Comment: I mean this: `(!Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->old_password, $user->password_hash)) die('somthing'); $this->addError($attribute, 'The Old Password not match.');`

Comment: I want to know if condition working correctly

Comment: @mahsaa,  i try to change  like your suggestion, and if i fill the old_password with password that not match my old password, the function return somthing

Comment: in controller in else body, please add `var_dump($model->errors)`

Comment: @mahsaa, array(1) { ["old_password"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "The Old Password not match." } }

Comment: So old_password has error. Are you sure it still not working?

Comment: @mahsaa,i want display that error  below the old_password field in the form, when user fill password that not match with their old_password

Comment: You are logged in or not. if you are not login 
Yii::$app->user->id did not get any id

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
public function findPasswords($attribute, $params, $validator)
{
    $user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
    if (!Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($this->old_password, $user->password_hash))
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The Old Password not match.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```